# PHP Function won't pick up variable's values

Tags: php, oop, calculator

I have written this as I am learning OOP PHP. I have been having some trouble with passing variables' values to functions. but it turns out that the functions won't read the variables' values. Please see below and advise.

```
<?php 


 class calculator {

    private $num1 = '1';
    private $num2 = '2';

    public function complete() {

        return $num1 * $num2;

    }

}

$calc = new calculator();
$result = $calc->complete();

echo $result;
```

Comment: Pass your numbers in a constructor. `public function __construct($num1, $num2) { $this->num1 = $num1; $this->num2 = $num2; }` would be nicer for your calculator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function complete() {

    return $num1 * $num2;

}
```

There is no variable `$num1` or `$num2` created in this function. Of course it does not *"read the variables' values"*.

What you want probably is:

```
public function complete() {

    return $this->num1 * $this->num2;

}
```

Have you read the chapter about [classes and objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) in the PHP Manual?

Answer (score 5):

You have to change this:

(With `$this` you access the class property and not any variable)

```
public function complete() {

    return $num1 * $num2;

}
```

to this:

```
public function complete() {

    return $this->num1 * $this->num2;
         //^^^^^ See here^^^^^

}
```

Comment: just as a side note - This is also how you explicitly call functions aswell. Use $this-> for anything inside your class

Comment: Thanks alot. That fixed it :) I was really trying to find a solution and couldn't understand the problem.

Comment: @JaySilva I personally think you accepted the wrong answer as this one both explains the issue and was submitted first. That's entirely your choice, but it's just the principle of the thing ;-)